# Change submit user in yarn with hive jdbc through sqldeveloper

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am connected to a kerberized cluster through sqldeveloper:

```
Host: <HOST_NAME>
Port: 10000
User: Username
database: default;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=REALM.COM;KrbHostFQDN=_HOST;krbServiceName=hive
```

Everything is working as expected, The query is submited to yarn with the user: **hive**.

[Yarn application submited with user hive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjhvK.png)

Is there a way that i can specify the user to submit the query to Yarn with the user **Username**?
In this way to be able to create policies in yarn to define the resources that users will use.

Comment: If I got this right the user 'hive' should become impersonated as user 'username', right?

Comment: Thank you, you give me some path about impersonate, i made some changes to hive properties on hive.server2.enable.doAs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that on my cluster there is a propertie hive.server2.enable.doAs, by default was set as false.

Setting the value as true solved the problem.

```
hive.server2.enable.doAs=true
```